# Initialize an array - won't compile?

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

```
public class Avalon {
    int[] ia = new int[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
         ia[i] = i;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I receive error: Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token at line: 
     int[] ia = new int[100];
Can someone tell me why?

Comment: you need a method... A class cannot contain for loops...

Comment: [Initializing Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make this change

```
public class Avalon {

    private int[] ia = new int[100];

    public void init(){
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
         ia[i] = i;
      }
    }

    public int[] getArray(){
      return ia;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Hello World");
    Avalon obj = new Avalon();
    obj.init();
    //get array
    int[] array = obj.getArray();

    }
}
```

Comment: What should I do if I want to access ia[i] inside the main function?

Comment: Can you explain why I have to do that?

Comment: because we access the private members of a class through public methods and not giving the direct access to private members. and methods and member variables should have access using object of that class only.

Comment: If I want access to a class-scope variable from the main function, what can I do btw?

Comment: for that you can make it static and access it using class name for example if you have some member variable say public static int DEFAULT=0;
then you can access it using int value =  Avalon.DEFAULT;

Comment: same goes for methods you can make a method static and access with class name. Avalon.getDefault();

Comment: read more here
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try like this:

```
public class Avalon {
    private void test() {
        int[] ia = new int[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
            ia[i] = i;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Avalon avalon = new Avalon();
        avalon.test();
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

since you can't put loops in the class without surrounding by method.

Comment: If I want to access ia[i] inside the main function, what can I do?

Comment: you can put ia outside the method, and creat another method to access the number or access ia[i] derectly in the main method.

Answer (score 0):

The class variables are initialised and flow starts from the main class. In the approach @buzzerbeater27 has used, the flow will never come to the for loop. You can use the following approach:

```
public class Avalon {
    static int[] ia = {1,2,3,4,5};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    System.out.println(ia[2]);
    }
}
```